# Uploadifive - formData passing through multi-select array

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I've been working on my new multi-upload system. Currently everything works sweet, but I run into a problem. Currently all my related form data send by 'formData' get through except for the multi-select form item. This should be an array, but for some reason it wont let me send the selected options.

```
var selectedAlbum = $('#upload_selection_albums').val();
var selectedFormats = $('#upload_selection_formats').val();

$('#file_upload').uploadifive({

'auto' : false,
'queueID' : 'queue',
'formData' : {'data_albums' : selectedAlbum,
'data_formats' : selectedFormats},
'uploadScript' : '/media/uploads/upload-file',

});
```

Anyone know how to solve it, I've been debugging for ages now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been workon on a proper fix and it turned out to be real simple. The formData element doesnt support arrays (as far I know). So I needed to pass my extra form data by the uploadScript property.

```
$(function() {

        $('#file-upload-test').on('click', function() {

            var uploadSettingsForm = $('#upload');
            var uploadSettingsFormData;

            uploadSettingsFormData = decodeURIComponent(uploadSettingsForm.serialize());
            uploadSettingsFormData = '/media/uploads/upload-file?' + uploadSettingsFormData;
            console.log(uploadSettingsFormData);

            $('#file_upload').data('uploadifive').settings.uploadScript = uploadSettingsFormData;
            $('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload');

            return false;

        });

        $('#file_upload').uploadifive({

            'auto'         : false,
            'queueID'      : 'queue',
            'itemTemplate' : '<div class="progress progress-striped active uploadifive-queue-item"><div class="bar progress-bar"><span class="filename"></span><span class="fileinfo"></span></div></div>',       
            'onDrop'       : function(file, fileDropCount) {
                $('#queue').removeClass('drag-drop-overlay');
            },
            'onSelect'     : function(queue) {
                $('#queue').removeClass('drag-drop-overlay');
            }

        });

    });
```